# why when I imported a project to my android studio the avd emulator does not work

Tags: import, project, android-virtual-device

I make a project in android studio and I can run it on the avd or my phone with no problem.  I imported a project from github, it installed ok but the avd will not run and the build output will error : Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings.  Please help. I have no idea how to go about fixing this.  I have tried several solution from the web...but no results.

Answer (score 0):

My layout from the imported project called for an android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.

By trial and error I tested the new androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout and everything with my avd emulator came back
to normal.